# Remove `Host` Header in Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I'm new to kubernetes and have setup a service with a few pods. I got this working, however I would like to remove or override the `Host` Header in the request. Can be overridden from the service somehow? I read into ingress but that will just reroute based on rules

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read into ingress but that will just reroute based on rules

With the addition that many of them offer support for [custom configuration snippets](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/nginx-0.12.0/docs/user-guide/annotations.md#configuration-snippet) to solve that very problem.

While provisioning Graylog2 last week, I took advantage of that annotation to add a custom header between the Ingress controller and the Graylog2 cluster, which would have otherwise required standing up a custom nginx or http server just for the one simple header. I highly recommend Ingress controllers, I think they're awesome.

Comment: Ah thanks for linking that. It looks like that's what I need. I don't care about the rules but that if required in the ingress controller tho. How would the ingress yaml look then?

Comment: the comment syntax won't allow me to show you in yaml, but the gist(haha) is `{"metadata":{"annotations":{"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet":"add_header \"host\" \"example.com\";\n"}}}` ([remarshal](https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/remarshal.rb) will cheerfully convert between that json and yaml)

Comment: Thanks! I nearly have it working! I tried to set `proxy_set_header Host "example.com";` in the annotation. It adds it correctly (nginx.conf) but that same directive already exists in that `Location` -  `proxy_set_header Host $best_http_host;`
I need to override it somehow because it doesn't pick up mine

Comment: Nvm I made a silly mistake with my url. Thanks for the help